# python subprocess to copy files from host to container

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, pipe, cp

Need help in python subprocess to copy file from host to container
here is the python code which I have tried

```
    import subprocess
    output=subprocess.check_output(['docker','ps'],
    universal_newlines=True)
    x=output.split('\n')
    for i in x:
        if i.__contains__("name_of_container"):
            container_id=i[:12]
    subprocess.call(["docker cp", "some_file.py", container_id:"/tmp"])
    subprocess.call(['docker','exec','-it', container_id,'bash'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import subprocess
output=subprocess.check_output(['docker','ps'],
universal_newlines=True)
x=output.split('\n')
for i in x:
  if i.__contains__("inspiring_sinoussi"):
      container_id=i[:12]
container_id_with_path=container_id+":/tmp"
subprocess.call(["docker", "cp", "/root/some_file.py", container_id_with_path])
subprocess.call(['docker','exec','-it', container_id,'bash'])
```

Actually in the `subprocess` call all the arguments are separated by comma. In your case `container_id:/tmp` should be a single argument since there is no any space inbetween them. As container_id is a variable in your case it can't be put with `:/tmp` together. So I created a new variable `container_id_with_path` which has the `:/tmp` path in it.

Running the script gives me the desired result.

```
$ python copy.py
/ # ls /tmp/
hsperfdata_root                          tomcat-docbase.1849924566121837123.9090
some_file.py
```

Comment: # NameError: name 'container_id' is not defined

Comment: I gave the correct indendation in for loop and if condition

Comment: Can you verfiy whether your variable `container_id` is properly defined. The code snippet I pasted above should work as it is. Also upvote and accept the answer if it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some errors of your code:

1. `container_id:"/tmp"` is not a valid python grammar
2. `docker cp` is not valid command in subprocess
3. `docker cp` not in for loop

So, I guess next is your fix:

```
for i in x:
    if i.__contains__("name_of_container"):
        container_id = i[:12]
        subprocess.call(["docker", "cp", "some_file.py", container_id + ":/tmp"])
```